# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'intern_to_update' is undefined

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to build a web app using Python Flask that can perform CRUD operations for a database that already exists in PostgreSQL. Below I'm trying to perform the "Update Operation"

Here is my table for the database;

```py
class Intern(db.Model):
    intern_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    intern_name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.intern_id
```

Following is my **update** function in **"app.py"**;

```py
@app.route('/update/<int:intern_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update(intern_id):

    intern_to_update = Intern.query.get_or_404(intern_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        intern_to_update.intern_name = request.form['name']

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/successful')

        except:
            return "There was a problem updating... Please try again!"

    else:
        return render_template('update.html', intern_to_update=intern_to_update)
```

Following is my **successful** function in **"app.py"**. This function creates the intern.

```py
@app.route('/successful', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def successful():

    if request.method == "POST":
        intern_name = request.form["intern_name"]
        new_intern = Intern(intern_name=intern_name)

        if not intern_name:
            show_error = "You need to fill out the forms required. Please try again."
            return render_template("fail.html", show_error=show_error)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_intern)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/successful')

        except:
            return "There was an error adding the new intern! Please try again"

    else:
        interns = Intern.query.order_by(Intern.date_created)
        return render_template("successful.html", interns=interns)
```

Here is my **"update.html"** file;

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Update{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
<h1>Update Operation</h1>

<br/><br/>

<form action="/update/{{intern_to_update.intern_id}}" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
  <b><p> {% block info %} Please enter the credentials below {% endblock %} </p></b>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Intern Name" name="name" value="{{intern_to_update.name}}">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Name">Create</button>
</form>

<br/>

<div class="mb-3">
  <b><p> Thank you, your operation is successfully completed! </p></b>
  </div>

</div> 

{% endblock %}
```

Lastly, below is where the update link is coming from in **"base.html"** file;

```
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('update', intern_id = intern_to_update.intern_id)}}">Update</a>
    </li>
```

There are no errors whatsoever with creating an intern. So my **"successful"** function is working without any mistakes. But I can't even see if my **"update"** function is working. Can someone please tell me why I'm getting this error I couldn't figure out? I checked other solutions for other users, which is usually adding "return render_template" for ELSE (GET) part for their code but I already did that.

Comment: `intern_to_update = Intern.query.get_or_404(intern_id)` should be `intern_to_update = Intern.query().get_or_404(intern_id)`

Comment: @rfkortekaas 
I did make the change you suggested but unfortunately, it didn't solve my error. Thanks anyway if you have another idea please do share.